# Microsoft Excel Hyperlink

Tags: microsoft-excel

Hi I am trying to create a hyperlink to a file which i can do ok but i need the hyperlink to use the value of a cell as the file name. for example my hyperlink is in cell B1 but and i am setting the hyperlink to a word document in my documents, however i would like the hyperlink to use the value of cell A1 as the file name for the hyperlink when it looks in my documents for  the word file. can this be done??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this formula in the cell where you want the hyperlink.

```
=HYPERLINK((CONCATENATE("D:\documents and settings\<User>\My Documents\", B1)) // eg: HYPERLINK(B1)
```

Comment: Sandeep sorry i dont think u get what i mean i want the hyperlink to use the cell value of A1 as the file name when it is opening from my documents

Comment: @Roger : How about the edited formula above?? The column B1 should have the filename (which is present in My documents folder)

Comment: Sandeep i used the edited formula with my path as shown =HYPERLINK((CONCATENATE("\Red_server\Documents\aaa\aaa CONTROLLED DOCS\INDIVIDUAL RECORD SHEETS\",A1562))) the ending was a requested modification by excel but this wont work. Any suggestions???

Comment: I got it Sandeep thanks for your help it is much appreciated